# android google maps zoom causes ontap method to be called

Tags: android, google-maps

In the on tap method, i am doing certain code. working good when user tap the map. But when user zooming in or out the map, sometimes the finger touch is detected as a tap, and the on tap method is called.

How to prevent this and clearly differentiate between the two actions ?

Thanks.

Comment: What API are you using? With Google Maps Android API v2 this does not happen.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, I didn't know about v2, i was using v1. Will check the enhancements in v2, but for now i used long touch event for on tap action.

Comment: You can try to use OnLongTap gesture to differentiate tap or zoom. I am not sure why you still using google map v1 since it will return many errors.  But just in case I let you know first that API v2 does not support any Touch Listener like v1 and you need to spend some times to search infromation yourslef how to do it.

Comment: @Maciej, thanks again for giving me the key.. have just used v2 and it is working great ..
@ Shawn, i was not using v2 cause i didn't know there is now v2 till Maciej told me .. I already managed to solve it with v1 before with temp solution as mentioned earlier  using long touch event for on tap action, but now i handled it with v2 too after reading it..